# How can I get some random numbers in a certain range?

Tags: scripts

I want to create a script that will create random numbers from 0 to 30,000 and save them in a text file.

I want all the numbers to be in one line.
I also want the numbers to be through 1 to 1,000,000 (I mean there should be 1 to 1,000,000 numbers in the file).

How do I do it? I want that script to test a program I made, and I want a script to automatically create numbers so I don't need to take time to write them on my own.

I also don't know anything about Linux scripting so if you can add some comments in your code I would be gladly accepted! :)

Comment: is that a homework? or do you want to learn shell scripting/programming?

Comment: neither. I want to make my life simplier :).  But i need to start someday. You also know that scripting in linux can help you  a lot in those small problems!

Comment: From 1 to 32768 is pretty simple: use the `$RANDOM` variable.

Comment: ok and for the others? But I want only those numbers not just randoms.

Comment: @NikosKLon so you want all numbers from 1 to N but shuffled (in a random order)?

Comment: yes where N is  32768. Then to saved in a txt file in my root folder.

Comment: ...and to be at most 1.000.000 of those random numbers. All in one line saperated every number with a whitespace

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`shuf`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/shuf) command:

```
shuf -e {1..N} | tr '\n' ' ' > some-file
```

For example:

```
$ shuf -e {1..10} | tr '\n' ' '
4 9 1 7 8 6 3 5 10 2
```

For very large numbers you might want to use a `for` loop and then shuffle it:

```
for i in {1..1000000}
do 
    echo $i
done |
shuf | tr '\n' ' ' > some-file
```

Comment: ok so we create large numbers until 1000000 right?

Comment: @NikosKLon all numbers from 1 to N. Isn't that what you said here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/543799/i-want-to-create-a-small-programm-in-linux/543803#comment744860_543799?

Comment: it will have all the numbers from 1 to N without repeat randomized. if you want them in the same line with spaces replace '\n' with ' '

Comment: thanks. How mnay of those will be created? eg If I want to create only 3 number or 500.000 how can I?

Comment: @NikosKLon each number exactly once. For larger numbers use the loop. I'm not sure what you mean by "only 3 numbers".

Comment: O.o i understand! I will test it tommorow cause in this part of planet Is night and I have school tomorrow. I will tell you then if I made it! Thanks in advanced!

Comment: and something more. Do i put the code as it is in a file? And how will be the extancion of the file? .sh?

Comment: @NikosKLon you can run it directly on a terminal, or put into a `.sh` file with `#!/bin/bash` as its first line.

Answer (score 2):

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
# The line above should always be on the top of
# an executable python file. It describes the 
# program this file should be interpreted with

# Import let's you extend the core functunality
# of python with code in extra "modules"
import random

# result is a string variable. Python is not strict
# about variable declaration or typing. They can
# be declared like this at any point in the programm 
# and may hold a variaty of data types. This one holds
# text now.
result = ""

# The imported module random offers the function randint.
# This function generates a number, where: 1 <= n <= 1000000
loop_iterations = random.randint(1,1000000)

# counter starts of at zero, counts up and, 
# on the last round, reaches loop_iterations -1
for counter in range(loop_iterations):
    new_random_integer = random.randint(0,30000)
    result += ", "
    # We can't add a number to a string, so we need
    # to convert it into a text representation first.
    result += str(new_random_integer)

# A file handler let's you interact with an opened file.
# open takes a path and a setting wether you want to 
# read/write. w means write.
file_handler = open('/tmp/output.txt', 'w')
file_handler.write(result)
file_handler.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

A very frequent technique for generating random numbers within specific range to is take random integer , and compute the remainder from integer division between the integer and the difference of the range limits. Basic idea is that remainder can only be from 0 to divisor, so we get that and then offset the resulting value by the low limit. I've used this technique multiple times when writing code in C.

Of course, this question is tagged with `scripts` and it is well possible to implement the same technique in `bash`. We can use `$RANDOM` variable generator and then take the integer into desired range using `bc` calculator. The script below does exactly that:

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

get_random_int(){

    echo "$low + $RANDOM % ( $high - $low + 1  )" | bc
}

main(){
    local howmany=$1
    local low=$2
    local high=$3

    local counter=0    
    while [ $counter -lt $howmany  ]
    do
        get_random_int
        counter=$(($counter+1))
    done
}

main "$@"
```

Basic usage:

```
$ ./random_in_range.sh 3 100 200                                                                                                      
184
110
179
```

The first argument is how many integers you want, second is low limit, and third argument is upper limit.